# Sublime Text Moving cursor up and down directly in between the tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm on OS X. How can I move my cursor around the code in Sublime Text (using keyboard only, obviously) in the way that it goes straight in between opening and closing tags?

For example I have `ul` list like this one below created with Emmet like `ul>li*3`. After hitting Tab button I end up in between first `li` tags. However when I type anything and hit arrow down my cursor goes at the end of next line. Moving around using Option+left/right is not convenient because cursor ends up just before `/` in `</li>` so I need to press left arrow twice to get where I want.

```
<ul>
  <li>hello 1</li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to move straight in between the tags? Will it work also in CSS and/or JS?

Answer (score 1):

Install Emmet plugin "emmet-sublume" for sublime text:

https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime

then use the following keyboard sequence: ⇧⌃T / Ctrl+Alt+J

More emmet shortcut keys can be find [here](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#available-actions)

Emmet website: http://emmet.io/

Answer (score 0):

For matching HTML tags, you might want to install the [Emmet plugin](http://emmet.io/).

When it’s installed, matching the tags is possible with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Matching curly brackets in CSS and JavaScript (and also other languages), is built-in and can be done with <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks all of you for answers. It happens that I've got Emmet plugin (installed via Package Browser) however shortcuts you mention 1) don't work 2) do different stuff. I have done some Google research but couldn't answer question why these shortcuts differ. (Abbreviations on Tab work well). Have you got any ideas why it's like so?

My setup is: OS X Yosemite 10.10.1 & Sublime Text 3

Comment: I'm on the exact same setup here and checked before posting to make sure it works. Does Control + M work for the curly brackets?

Comment: No. It minimizes the window.

Comment: Hmm, in the default OS X settings, Cmd + M should minimize the window, not Ctrl + M. Did you change this? You could reassign the “Jump to Matching Bracket” feature to another shortcut to solve this.